# Marionette.js - access to behavior functions from itemView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

At first i had Marionette.js itemView with plenty functions inside. So, i would like to move some of them to Behavior. But i have met big problem - i can't use behavior functions from itemView directly. Here is my initial code:

```
var NodeView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    showDefault: function(){
        /* some code */
        this.showOther();
    },
    // Initiates
    showOther: function(){
        /* some code */    
    }
});
```

as u see i trigger one node method inside other. I need do same after moving one function inside behavior

```
var NodeView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    behaviors: {
        NodeBehavior: {
            behaviorClass: NodeBehavior
        }
    },
    showDefault: function(){
        /* some code */
        this.showOther(); /* how can i trigger this function ? */
    }        
});

var NodeBehavior = Marionette.Behavior.extend({
    showOther : function(){
        /* some code */    
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your view you can manually call methods within a behavior by using `triggerMethod`

For example, here is a mock view with a `Modal` behavior attached. Assume upon initialization we would like to call the `onSayWho` method on the Modal behavior. The following code demonstrates how you would do that:

```
define([
    'marionette',
    'behaviors/Modal',
    'tpl!templates/tpl.html'
], function(
    Mn,
    Modal,
    tpl
) {
  var view = Mn.LayoutView.extend({
    template: tpl,

    behaviors: {
        Modal: {
            behaviorClass: Modal
        }
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        var data = 'Mike Jones!';
        this.triggerMethod('sayWho', data);
    },
});

return view;
});
```

and here would be the Modal behavior code:

```
define([
    'marionette'
], function (
    Mn
) {
   var Modal = Mn.Behavior.extend({
     onSayWho: function(name) {
         console.log('who? ' + name);
     }
});

return Modal;
});
```

Be sure to note that the behavior's function name needs to have `on` before it. IE the view calls `this.triggerMethod('sayWho', data)`, whereas the actual function name in the behavior is `onSayWho`

Answer (score 0):

Is the `NodeView` and `NodeBehavior` defined in the same file like that?

You will need to have your NodeBehavior defined above your NodeView:

```
var NodeBehavior = Marionette.Behavior.extend({
    showOther : function(){
        /* some code */    
    }    
});

var NodeView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    behaviors: {
        NodeBehavior: {
            behaviorClass: NodeBehavior
        }
    },
    showDefault: function(){
        /* some code */
        this.showOther(); /* how can i trigger this function ? */
    }        
});
```

Otherwise, NodeBehavior isn't defined when you are setting `behaviorClass: NodeBehavior`

Comment: thanks for the answer. I use requirejs : my itemview initiated only after behavior has finished its initiating